# Can't able to figure out how to ensure last pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I'm not able to figure out how to ensure only content1 match and not content2.

```
var re  =  "//(\d{1,2})/";

var content1 = "/digital-cameras/point-shoot/10";
var content2 = "/digital-cameras/10-point-shoot";
```

How to check on end of line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one or two digits *at the end*, put `$` at the end of the regular expression. Also, in JavaScript, regular expression literals are written with `/.../`, not `"..."`:

```
var re  =  /(\d{1,2})$/;
// $ here -----------^
```

There, the `/` at either end is not part of the expression, it marks the start and end of the expression (like `"` and `'` do for strings).

`$` is called an "anchor" and it means "the end of the input." (There's another one, `^`, which means "the beginning of the input.")

Comment: More about regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

**Escape forward slashes and use end of line anchor `$`** to make sure digits are matched at line end only:

```
var re  =  "/\/\d{1,2}$/";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match against the end-of-string, using the `$` anchor:

```
/(\d{1,2})$/
```

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).